# Using Guice, how can I inject a bounded-wildcard class?

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, guice, bounded-wildcard

Using Guice, I want to inject a bounded-wildcard class.  To be clear, I don't want to inject an *object*, but inject a *class type*.  The would read:

```
class A {
   Class<? extends SuperClass> a;
   @Inject A(Class<? extends SuperClass> a) {
      this.a = a.;
   }
}
```

How can I correctly bind the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this binding:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Class<? extends SuperClass>>() {})
    .toInstance(SubClass.class);
```

Comment: Thanks so much; I should have been able to figure this one out.  Worked great!